# A self-isometry of the sphere of a strictly convex Banach space that does not move basic vectors

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, group-actions, convex-analysis

> **Problem.** Let $n\in\mathbb N$, $X$ be a strictly convex $n$-dimensional real Banach space, $S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ be the unit sphere of $X$, and $e_1,\dots,e_n\in S_X$ be linearly independent points. Let $f:S_X\to S_X$ be an isometry such that $f(e_i)=e_i$ for all $i\le n$. Is $f$ the identity map of $S_X$?

**Remark 1.** The answer is affirmative if $n\le 3$. For $n=3$ this follows from a [known fact](https://jfdmath.sitehost.iu.edu/seminar/transformationgroupsb.pdf) that any action of a compact group on the $2$-sphere is equivalent to the linear action of a compact subgroup of $O(3)$ on $S^2$.

**Remark 2.** A Banach space is *strictly convex* if every convex subset of its unit sphere contains at most one point.

**Example** ([Javier Cabello Sanchez](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02461)): Consider the strictly convex 3-dimensional Banach space $X=(\mathbb R^3,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ endowed with the $\ell_3$-norm $$\Vert(x,y,z)\Vert=\sqrt[3]{|x|^3+|y|^3+|z|^3}$$and basis
$$\mathbf e_1=\tfrac1{\sqrt[3]{6}}(1,1,-\sqrt[3]{4}),\quad \mathbf e_2=\tfrac1{\sqrt[3]{6}}(1,-\sqrt[3]{4},1),\quad \mathbf e_3=\tfrac1{\sqrt[3]{6}}(-\sqrt[3]{4},1,1).$$
For the point $\mathbf x=\tfrac1{\sqrt[3]{3}}(1,1,1)\in S_X$ and every $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ we have
$$\Vert \mathbf e_i-\mathbf x\Vert=\Vert \mathbf e_i+\mathbf x\Vert=\sqrt[3]{\tfrac43+\sqrt[3]{2}},$$
which means that the point $\mathbf x$ on the sphere $S_X$ **is not** uniquely determined by its distances to the six points $\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3, -\mathbf e_1,-\mathbf e_2,-\mathbf e_3$. This Example shows that the **Problem** cannot be reduced to the level of individual points.

Comment: Which distance do you put on the sphere ? The restricted distance or the path metric ?

Comment: @NicolasTholozan The restricted distance (but it determines the path metric anyway).